# Is it possible to set FolderBrowserDialog.RootFolder to an arbitrary path from a string?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to do this

```
FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
dlg.RootFolder = "C:\SomeUserSelectedFolder";
```

But `RootFolder` is a `System.Environment.SpecialFolder`.

Does this mean I can only set that to places like MyDocuments or the Desktop?!?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's correct: if the assigned value of `RootFolder` is not one of the `Environment.SpecialFolder` values then [an InvalidEnumArgumentException is raised](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.rootfolder.aspx).

You can set [SelectedPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.selectedpath.aspx), though:

> If the SelectedPath property is set before showing the dialog box, the
>   folder with this path will be the selected folder, as long as
>   SelectedPath is set to an absolute path that is a subfolder of
>   RootFolder (or more accurately, points to a subfolder of the shell
>   namespace represented by RootFolder).

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll mess with that and come back to accept the answer once it's working. :)

Comment: I'm running into another problem, but this has answered my question. Thanks!